# Jquery draggable element when cloned not draggable

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable

After looking at all the jquery draggable clone possible duplicates, I still can't find the answer to what must be a fairly common issue.

I have a series of DIV elements that I can clone successfully, but each clone loses it's draggable capability, I've looked at the generated code and still can't work out why this is.

Any clues please?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Sortable - Cloning issue</title>
<style>
.bgblue {
background-color:#9CF;
}
.bgred {
      background-color:#F36;
  }

  </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>


  <script>

  function seCopyBox(x) {
    z = $('.seBox').eq(x).clone();
    z.insertAfter($('.seBox').eq(x));
} 

$(function() {
$( ".seBox" ).draggable();
  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>



<div class="seBox bgblue">
<p onClick="javascript:var x=$(this).closest('.seBox').index();seCopyBox(x)">COPY</p>
<p>Div A</p>
</div>

<div class="seBox bgred">
<p onClick="javascript:var x=$(this).closest('.seBox').index();seCopyBox(x)">COPY</p>
<p>Div B</p>
</div>

<div class="seBox bgblue">
<p onClick="javascript:var x=$(this).closest('.seBox').index();seCopyBox(x)">COPY</p>
<p>Div C</p>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: If you want save events on cloned element, put true inside brackets: like this clone(true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call `draggable()` again for the cloned element after it is appended to the DOM

```
 function seCopyBox(x) {
   z = $('.seBox').eq(x).clone();
   z.insertAfter($('.seBox').eq(x)).draggable();
}
```

and i would go with clean jquery click function rather that inline javascript..

```
$(document).on('click','.seBox p',function(){
   var x=$(this).closest('.seBox').index();
    var z = $('.seBox').eq(x).clone();
    z.insertAfter($('.seBox').eq(x)).draggable();
}
```

remove the inline javascript and the `seCopyBox` function...

Comment: looks like the way to go even z should be local, no?!

Comment: yupp!!! thanks @roasted (again.. 3rd time today for letting me know about my mistakes..) :).... and let me tell you,you  have a good eye...

Comment: This is not really your mistake, it is more a mistake done by OP ;)

Comment: That works - thank you! And thanks also for the bonus clean jquery advice too, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is better `.draggable()` should be placed at cloned element.

```
$(document).on('click','.seBox p',function(){
var x=$(this).closest('.seBox').index();
var z = $('.seBox').eq(x).clone().draggable();
z.insertAfter($('.seBox').eq(x));
}
```

instead

```
$(document).on('click','.seBox p',function(){
var x=$(this).closest('.seBox').index();
var z = $('.seBox').eq(x).clone();
z.insertAfter($('.seBox').eq(x)).draggable();
}
```

Just my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I didn't know that - what would the reason be for this?

Comment: Of all the solution, this was the key to make it work, thank you!